# Show distance of route

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

First off, I would like to say I'm quite new to Swift. The simplest answer is probably the best in my situation.

I currently have some code that draws a route from my current location to the Grand Canyon, using the mapkit. The starting- and ending location is build in the code:

```
let soucrceCoordinates = locationManager.location?.coordinate
//coordinates off the grand canyon, placeholder
let destCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.1070, -112.1130)

let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: soucrceCoordinates!)
let destPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destCoordinates)

let sourceItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
let destItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destPlacemark)

let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
directionRequest.source = sourceItem
directionRequest.destination = destItem
directionRequest.transportType = .automobile
```

Now I would like to calculate the distance of this route (not as the crow flies). The preferable unit would be meters. Is there anyway to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an `MKDirections` instance as well, not just an `MKDirectionsRequest` and call `MKDirections.calculate` to calculate the navigation routes.

```
let sourceCoordinates = locationManager.location?.coordinate
//coordinates of the grand canyon, placeholder
let destCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.1070, longitude: -112.1130)

let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceCoordinates!)
let destPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destCoordinates)

let sourceItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
let destItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destPlacemark)

let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
directionRequest.source = sourceItem
directionRequest.destination = destItem
directionRequest.transportType = .automobile

let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
directions.calculate(completionHandler: { response, error in
    guard error == nil, let response = response, let route = response.routes.first else {return}
    print("Distance:\(route.distance)meters")
})
```